# Laravel 5.4 | Fetching data from Pivot Table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have 4 tables in my database:

Table 1: Category

```
---|------
id | name
---|------
1  | Cars
```

In 'Category' model class I have defined the following relationship:

```
class Category {
    public function fields() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Field');
    }
}
```

Table 2: Field

```
id | name
---|-------
1  | Make
```

In 'Field' model class I have defined the following relationship:

```
class Field {
    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Table 3: Field_Options

```
field_id | value
---------|-------
1        | Audi
1        | BMW
```

In 'FieldOption' model class I have defined the following relationship:

```
class FieldOption extends Model
{
    public function field() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Field');
    }
}
```

Table 4: Category_Field

```
category_id | field_id
------------|-------
1           | 1
```

Now I need to fetch all the fields and field_options for category_id=1. How can I achieve this using Laravel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define relationship between Field and FieldOptions

```
public function options() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\FieldOption');
}
```

Then you can eager load all relationships like this

```
$category = Category::with('fields.options')->find(1);
//Get category 1, with all fields and their respectif fieldOptions
```